# Wind a cable using a motor

Tags: motor, dc-motor, mechanical

I have a very simple question yet I'm unable to find any solution.

I've bought a simple DC motor, associated to a gear box that can deliver 16,5N.cm, which is far enough.

I'd like to transform the rotation into an horizontal translation. The best way I can think about is to attach a cable to a motor, so it will wind/unwind it, and the cable will pull directly on the piece I want to translate.

The motors looks like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmx1i.png

How do I attach "something" to the output of the motor ? It's all smooth, I can't attach something to it. What is the thing I need to wind my cable around ?

Comment: This is not an electrical question

Comment: @Daniel There's a lot of mechanical/motors related questions on EE.

Comment: use a pulley with a setscrew to press against the shaft.  For a more secure drive connection, you could file a flat on the shaft for the setscrew to press against.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxyokNeSTwE also http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/459/how-do-you-attach-something-temporary-to-a-smooth-metal-shaft And the "PhD version" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnuEmfClX9s

Comment: Have a look at how model aircraft props are fastened to their shafts - they often use a collect type fastener that does not need a "flat" on the shaft or a set screw. A nut concentric with the shaft is tightened and drives a cone into the collets expanding them and locking the prop to the shaft. These can work at several kW at 10's of 1000's of RPM.

Comment: This sounds like a 23W or so motor, so I wouldn't go with something very improvised.

Comment: What's the diameter of the shaft, by the way?

Comment: In case you're wondering, I'm asking because a [tapered bushing](http://machinedesign.com/site-files/machinedesign.com/files/archive/motionsystemdesign.com/images/Flanged-bushings0896.jpg) might be what you want, but it's not usually available below a certain shaft size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to find some sort of spool or pulley that fastens to the driveshaft of your motor using a [set screw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_screw).

Comment: That would be the most horrible option of those I've linked above.

Comment: Then provide your own answer to the question.

Comment: Some of us don't desperately need to answer mostly off-topic questions for points. I did answer in a comment.

Comment: Then don't.  Quit wasting everyone's time with petty nit-picking.